# Updating Web Map Service (WMS) by default when data amended in Oracle source tables?

Tags: wms, oracle-dbms

I have a WMS which source data is held in Oracle.

Every year an amendment to the view in Oracle is run to update records.

Does the web map service need to be re-published once these amendments are made or are these updates to the data automatically reflected in the WMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally WMS Servers rendering the content on-the-fly and therefor the resulting map image should be up-to-date.

If you're using a Tile-Mapping Server (like MapProxy, GeoWebCache, TileCache, etc) on top of this WMS Service its recommend to seed/force the layers based on your database tables that were updated.

Comment: Good comment about tile caching.